# rendering text and html in a block of content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to produce the following html using rails helpers in a helper file:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
  Browse File<%= file_field_tag :file %>
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control file-display" placeholder="" style="width: 250px; display: inline">
```

This is what I tried:

```
def file_helper(form, attr)
  span = content_tag :span, class:"btn btn-default btn-file" do
    "Browse File" + form.file_field(attr)
  end
  input = content_tag(:input, nil, type: 'text', class:"form-control file-display",   style:"width: 250px; display: inline")
  span + input
end

<%= file_helper f, :document %>
```

Unfortunately the resulting html looks like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">Browse File&lt;input id="document_document" name="document[document]" type="file" /&gt;</span>
<input class="form-control file-display" style="width: 250px; display: inline" type="text">
```

The problem is the nested input of the span is not rendered as html. It is rendered as text along with "Browse File". How can I get the "Browse File" to render as text and the input to render as html within the outer span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue when combining "safe" Strings which are wrapped by a SafeBuffer and unsafe strings which aren't.

> SafeBuffer inherits from String, overriding +, concat and << so that:
>
> - If the other String is safe (another SafeBuffer), the buffer concatenates it directly
> - If the other String is unsafe (a plain String), the buffer escapes it first, then concatenates it
>
> (source: [click](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/))

In your case `form.file_field(attr)` yields a proper safe buffer but "Browse File" does not. As a result, when they are combined, they are now a regular String, not wrapped by a SafeBuffer.

In the last line, you again combine a properly wrapped String `input` with the previous unwrapped String `span` which leads to `span` being escaped.

[`.html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) creates a SafeBuffer wrapper for a String so wrapping `"Browse File".html_safe + form.file_field(attr)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(span + input).html_safe` [Check this out...](http://www.tigraine.at/2012/08/23/when-to-use-raw-and-when-to-use-html_safe)