# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu on Rails with helper methods bypassing link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu using a helper method in Rails, but when I had the ul for the links within the dropdown, it bypasses my dropdown link tag...

application_helper.rb

```
  def nav_bar(c='nav nav-pills')
    content_tag(:ul, class: "#{c}") do
      yield
    end
  end

  def nav_dropdown(text)
    html_options = {data: {toggle:"dropdown"}, class:"dropdown-toggle", role:"button", aria:{haspopup:"true", expanded:"false"}}
    content_tag(:li, role:"presentation", class:"dropdown") do
      link_to raw(text + content_tag(:span, "",class:"caret")   ),"#", html_options
      nav_bar('dropdown-menu') do yield end

    end
  end
```

_menu.html.erb

```
  <%= nav_bar do %>
    ...

<% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= nav_link t('menu.list_companies'), companies_path %>
    <%= nav_dropdown t('menu.configurations') do %>
     <%= nav_link t('menu.edit_process_types'), process_types_path %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

html generated when I have the navbar line `nav_bar('dropdown-menu') do yield end`

```
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a data-method="get" href="/process_types"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: pt.menu.edit_process_types"> Edit Process Types</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

html generated when I remove the navbar line `nav_bar('dropdown-menu') do yield end`from the helper method

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
    Configurações<span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I'm wanting to reach:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
    Configurações<span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a data-method="get" href="/process_types"><span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: pt.menu.edit_process_types"> Edit Process Types</span></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Any ideas on what is happening here and how to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that content_tag was only outputing last line.
Then I found this: [rendering text and html in a block of content_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760772/rendering-text-and-html-in-a-block-of-content-tag) , where I saw a possible way to do this.

In the end, i changed application_helper.rb with

```
  def nav_dropdown(text)

    html_options = {data: {toggle:"dropdown"}, class:"dropdown-toggle", role:"button", aria:{haspopup:"true", expanded:"false"}}
    content_tag(:li, role:"presentation", class:"dropdown") do

     link= link_to(raw(text + content_tag(:span, "",class:"caret")  ),"#", html_options)

     nav= nav_bar("dropdown-menu") do
        yield
       end

      link + nav
    end

  end
```

and it finally worked getting the desired html:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
  Configurações <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="active"><a data-method="get" href="/process_types">Processos Modelo</a>
          </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```